# asterisk zoiper registration failed

Tags: asterisk

I'm using Asterisk to register sip client but it shows me this message:

NOTICE[3212]: chan_sip.c:25797 handle_request_register: Registration from '' failed for '192.xx.xx.xx:5060' - Wrong password

that's what I configure in sip.conf:

```
[user1]
type=friend
host=dynamic
secret=root
context=users
nat=no

[user2]
type=friend
host=dynamic
secret=rootroot
context=users
nat=no
```

in extensions.conf:

```
[users]
exten=>6001,1,Dial(SIP/user1,20)
exten=>6002,1,Dial(SIP/user2,20)
```

when I use sip show users, I don't find any user.

Answer (score 0):

u forgot to add
[user1]
...
defaultuser=user1

[user2]
...
defaultuser=user2

Answer (score 0):

It looks like to be asked in Server Fault though.

Error says 'Wrong Password' though did you make sure its correct?
How did you set up Zoiper?

I recommend you set keepalive as well.
Otherwise zoiper will be unregistered from Asterisk.
And also make sure you set up zoiper to work background if you want to take call all the time.

You can turn on background functionality here.
Settings > Incoming Calls